# How do Nautilus media handlers work?

Tags: nautilus, multimedia, mime-type

Nautilus has options for what to do when media devices are added.

[image: Media Handling Preferences]

How does Nautilus know what applications to make available in these drop-down menus?

How do applications plug themselves in to this mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mimetypes-registering.html.en:

> Registering applications to handle MIME types is fairly straightforward. Applications are registered by creating a `MimeType` key in their `.desktop` entry file and listing each MIME type separated by a semicolon. The `MimeType` key should only be used in `.desktop` files whose `Type` key has the value `Application`. For more information on `.desktop` files, see [Section 2.3 ― Desktop Entry Files](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en).

Nautilus gets this infomation from the `mimeinfo.cache` files located in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` and `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/` that are created by `update-desktop-database`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it this is handled by the MIME, the same thing that handles what application opens which files. system (sorry I don't have the full details).

EDIT: DoR answered as I was typing. He nailed it.